# How do you prevent "Disable-SPFeature : Cannot complete this action. Please try again." errors?

Tags: powershell

When I try to run this cmdlet, I receive the following errors (only sometimes):

Disabling feature:   SPFeatureDefinition Name=FeatureDefinition/b89234a6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-200dd03e1fdd ( XXXStructures_XXXContentTypes , b89234a6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-200dd03e1fdd )
VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Disable-SPFeature.
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Disable-SPFeature" on Target "Site Scope 
|b89234a6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-200dd03e1fdd".
Disable-SPFeature : Cannot complete this action.
Please try again.

The part of the script that is producing this is...

```
foreach ($feature in $features) {
    if ($feature -ne $null) {
        Write-Host "`nDisabling feature:  " $feature "(" $feature.DisplayName "," $feature.ID ")"
        Disable-SPFeature $feature -url <my URL> -Confirm:$false -Force -verbose
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }
```

Comment: Check the ULS logs for more detailed error information.

Comment: Actually using -force should swallow all exceptions (which is why you should NEVER use it unless you do get errors trying to disable it). As Jasper say, post relevant ULS log entries so we can see stack trace of error